# A terminal inside a qt GUI application

Tags: c++, qt, console, terminal, windows-console

I have recently finished the UI for my console application with qt and I want to have a panel (container is not important) for a console version too.

Something like this:

[image]

How can I do this?
I need solutions for Windows and for Linux.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [QTermWidget](http://qtermwidget.sourceforge.net/) sounds as if it should be usable for this situation.

I haven't tried it myself (I'm not a Qt developer). Also, it doesn't seem to be very well maintained, but at least give it a try.

Comment: Thanks for a solution. This works on linux. I will wait some time for a windows version and then accept your answer :)